# Basic div replacement width a fade transition

Tags: jquery

OK I have looked for something simple I can build on but most of the jQuery stuff I find is already way to complex for me to manipulate.

My idea is to have one big div that I can put any html content image/text etc and under that sub divs that also can have text and a background image or what ever I choose and they way I want it to function is if you hover over the div thumbnail it will change the content in the big div in a nice fade transition and also the thumbnail will be able to link.

Similar to this: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/img-replacement.html but with a nice fade transition and not using images but divs so I can do what I like within them.

Possibly the thumbnails in the code to easily add more or less without adding more and more lines of jquery so it could almost be dynamicly created using a db at a later date.

Sounds simple in my head! maybe not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/vrqdh/2/)

Its Simple You just have to use `Html()` and `fadeIn(),fadeOut()` on click of small div.

I think code written is simple enough to understand. even you have some problem just ask ;)
​

Comment: Cheers for the response, I'm a web designer and I play with sliders etc almost every day but I can't write jQuery as such but I can manipulate existing code to a point, And i'm really keen to learn however just for this project I need help with a kick start, don't have the time to learn just yet... to busy!

Comment: Sorry didnt click on the link, I just thought you were sending me to the main site, thanks!

Comment: Actually while I have your attention you couldn't help me with one other thing regarding this project, can I have the thumbnail click to show separate unique content in the main div? so each thumbnail has its own unique content div... hope that makes sense.

Comment: yes that easy you should just change this line in the code  `newHtml=$(this).html();` hear newHtml is a variable and you can assign any html in it

Comment: Hi again, sorry I had a play and broke the crap out of it, you couldn't update that Fiddle link for me, so every thumbnail has its own unique main content div to display, again sorry to be a pain.